# transparent amplitude overlay on video without black box

Tags: ffmpeg, video

This is the command that I run:

`ffmpeg -y -i source_file.wav -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x175:colors=White:mode=line,format=yuv420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay=0:1000[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest output9.mp4`

The output video looks like this:

[image]

As you can see behind the visualization of the amplitude is a black box.
Is it possible to make this box transparent so that the visualization is overlayed directly on the video?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/27868/ffmpeg-transparent-background-with-showwaves-or-showspectrum Should get you there

Answer (score 0):

Add `format=rgba` after the `showwaves` filter:

`ffmpeg -y -i source_file.wav -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x175:colors=White:mode=line,format=rgba[v];[1:v][v]overlay=0:1000[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest output9.mp4`

- The `format` filter converts the output of `showwaves` to RGBA pixel format, and the alpha channel of the "black" background is zero (fully transparent).
- The `overlay` filter overlays the showwaves result (with the transparent background) over the JPEG image.
  The output is converted to `yuv420p` pixel format (without transparency).